# How is this int formatted to represent date and time?

Tags: java, datetime, formatting, integer, overriding

I am studying a method I have found in an application called 'getDateTime'. It returns a date and time as one integer. This is then converted by the app  and displayed on a label in 24 hour format.

I am not sure how the method is converting the integer it returns - it will not be possible to see this code.

What I can do is override the returned integer and see what date and time is displayed to try and figure out how it is formatted. I would like to be able to convert any date and time to an int of the same format.

Here are some random overrides I did, and what the corresponding printed result was. I have also recorded when the app crashed to give an idea of when the format may be invalid:

- 0 - 00 January 2000 0:00
- 1 - 01 January 2000 0:00
- 2 - 02 January 2000 0:00
- 3 - 03 January 2000 0:00
- 33 - 01 February 2000 0:00
- 65 - 01 March 2000 0:00
- 97 - 01 April 2000 0:00
- 513 - 01 January 2001 0:00
- 545 - 01 February 2001 0:00
- 1025 - 01 January 2002 0:00
- 1057 - 01 February 2002 0:00
- 2002 - Crashed app
- 65537 - 01 January 2000 0:01
- 131073 - 01 January 2000 0:02
- 4194305 - 01 January 2000 1:00
- 8388609 - 01 January 2000 2:00
- 100001 - 01 June 2067 0:01
- 1000001 - 01 March 2033 0:15
- 1029601 - Crashed app
- 1129601 - 01 March 2030 0:17
- 1838382 - 14 Octoboer 2006 0:28
- 35000106551 - 23 February 2031 24:43
- 45000106551 - 23 February 2017 8:55
- 45000106552 - 24 February 2017 8:55

If you need anymore examples to figure out the format, please ask away! I just can't see any correlation, other than the fact that changing the right most digit can be used to change the current day.

Comment: Could you post the output for these numbers: 1, 2, 3, 33, 65, 97, 513, 545, 1025, 1057, 65537, 131073, 4194305, 8388609

Comment: Are you sure about the last three values (45000..., 35000...)? These numbers exceed the range of integers, so it seems that you can feed long values into the method?

Comment: Well the thing is I don't believe the value may really be an integer. It may be a double, or something else. What I am using is not always accurate when trying to interpret the variable types. It also thinks strings are integers. I will update my post now with these numbers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the components of the date (year, month, day, hour, minute) are packed into fields of specific width (similar to the way dates were stored in a [FAT directory entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_of_the_FAT_file_system#Directory_entry)).

This method will pack the information into the required format:

```
public static int packTimeFields(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute) {
    checkRange("year", year, 2000, 2127);
    checkRange("month", month, 1, 12);
    checkRange("day", day, 1, 31);
    checkRange("hour", hour, 0, 23);
    checkRange("minute", minute, 0, 59);
    return day + (month-1) * 32 + (year-2000) * 512 + minute * 65536 + hour * 65536 * 64;
}

private static void checkRange(String name, int value, int min, int max) {
    if (value < min || value > max)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(name+" "+value+" is not in valid range "+min+"..."+max);
}
```

---

This code nicely explains the shown examples except

> 1129601 - 01 March 2030 0:17

I would expect this to be

> 1129601 - 01 May 2030 0:17

Comment: Amazing response! It doesn't quite seem to be working yet though. I tested with today's date, 24/02/2017 and the time 2:10pm (ensuring I passed the parts correctly to the function) and the output was 2432870465536058720256. I think this number is too large to override with as it made the app unstable

Comment: I found an error in my code... I will fix and retry! :D

Comment: it works! Fantastic! That's amazing that you figured it out!! Thank you so much!!!! Marked as correct!